# Jupyter Docker with password text

Tags: docker, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to run a Jupyter docker, how can I pass in the password text when running the docker?

So far I couldn't figure how to pass in my password text in the docker run, but to generate the password hash prior to the run.

```
$ HASH=$(docker run -it jupyter/minimal-notebook python -c "from notebook import auth; print(auth.passwd('${JupyterPassword}')))"
$ docker run -it -d -p 8080:8888 -e GEN_CERT=yes jupyter/minimal-notebook start-notebook.sh --NotebookApp.password=${HASH}
```

Is there anyway I can pass in ${JupyterPassword} directly without having to generate the hash?

Comment: create hash onetime then save to config file and then mount the file? something like `-v mypass.conf:/root/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py`

Comment: I need to rotate the password everytime I create a new notebook, thus asking for new password on creating will be ideal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that I can override the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` in `jupyter/base-notebook`, and move it to the `/home/jovyan/.jupyter/` to get executed on load

So I added these lines in `jupyter_notebook_config.py`

```
if 'PASSWORD' in os.environ:
  password = os.environ['PASSWORD']
  if password:
    print("Password updated")
    c.NotebookApp.password = passwd(password)
  del os.environ['PASSWORD']
```

And move them when container starts up

```
COPY jupyter_notebook_config.py /home/jovyan/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```